# start-dfs.sh datanode fails in Single node mode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I launched the script start-dfs.sh to start hdfs, but it doesn't run datanode (the namenode is runnimg and I can create folders correctly). So when I try to put data in the hdfs, I got the following error:

```
hdfs dfs -put history25 /mydata
16/03/05 20:42:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/03/05 20:42:30 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /mydata/history25._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3034)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:723)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1476)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:449)
put: File /mydata/history25._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Start the namenode bin/hadoop namenode. Check for errors, if any.

Start the datanodes bin/hadoop datanode. Check for errors, if any.

Now start the task-tracker, job tracker using 'bin/start-mapred.sh'

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately I got a failure in the system that made the utilization of hadoop impossible. However, before this problem, when I launched the start-dfs.sh script, it start only the namenode but datanode didn't start. Once the problem with my server will be fixed I will report the results. Thanks again